# Evaluate symbolic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, evaluate

I've defined a function in Matlab like this:
`clg = 2*pi*(alpha-alphai+0.5*A(1));`
where A is an array which depends on `alpha`.
I want to evaluate `clg` for `aplha=0.53`.
I've tried `subs(clg, alpha, 0.53)`, but It gives me a bunch of weird errors:

```
Error using sym/subs>normalize (line 210)
Entries in second argument must be scalar.

Error in sym/subs>mupadsubs (line 136)
[X2,Y2,symX,symY] = normalize(X,Y); %#ok

Error in sym/subs (line 124)
    G = mupadsubs(F,X,Y);

Error in integral (line 45)
subs(clg, alpha, 0.53)
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: what is `alphai` in the equation?

Comment: alphai is a parameter, its value is aprox 0.53

Comment: Ok so you have both `alpha` and `alphai` cancelling each other in your equation?

Comment: Yeah, but `A(1)` still depends on `alpha`.

Comment: Please add complete example code to your question which allows to reproduce the problem. Maybe some variable initialization is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem about your question.

```
>> syms x x1 x2
>> clg = 2*pi*(x-x1+0.5*x2);
>> subs(clg,x,0.53)

ans =

2*pi*(x2/2 - x1 + 53/100)
```

Comment: This is not analogical.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reproduce the problem, but this works:

```
syms x
%A is a symbolic matrix that depends on x
A = inv([10*x, 2*x, 3*x;
        4*x, 10, 6*x;
        7*x, 8*x, 10*x])
%y is a symbolic expression defined such that
%it depends on A, but collapses to an expression of x
y = x + 0.5*A(2,2)
%subs returns a symbolic (in this case fraction) evaluation:
subs(y, x, 3)
%eval returns a numeric evaluation:
x = 3
eval(y)
```

(I have encountered the same error message as you in my own code, but have not yet hunted down its source.)